# How to fix schema markup error and warning on Blogger theme?

Tags: html, data-structures, schema

I placed schema codes on my Blogger template. For my Blog, no error and no warning. However, for each Blog Posting, it has the same error and same warnings on about line 3,000 as follows:

**Error :**

```
Publisher: no Publisher value
Warning: dateModified: please provide value
Warning: mainEntityOfPage: please provide value
```

Blog URL: https://www.legal-advice.hk
One of the blog posts: 
https://www.legal-advice.hk/2014/02/divorce-procedure.html

I can't see anything wrong with my schema code:

```
&quot;datePublished&quot;: &quot;2014-02-15&quot;,
&quot;dateModified&quot;: &quot;2019-11-19&quot;,
&quot;mainEntityOfPage&quot;: &quot;https://www.legal-advice.hk/2014/02/defamation.html&quot;,
&quot;publisher&quot;: {
    &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;Organization&quot;,
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Choi Lawyer&quot;,
    &quot;logo&quot;: {
&quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ImageObject&quot;,
&quot;url&quot;: &quot;https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Nj9XcEaEsXI/XgwMfMx4i4I/AAAAAAAABFI/up42xdzmzEIxpY4pSRdD7PDJPv5YzlNQwCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/Choi%2BLawyer.jpg&quot;,
&quot;width&quot;:&quot;349&quot;,
&quot;height&quot;:&quot;350&quot;
}
},
```

Anyone knows how to fix the above issues please? Thank you very much in advance.

Thanks !